# Package javax.mail does not exist

Tags: grails, jakarta-mail, javax

I have grails project.

[image: show img]

All dependencies are correct and I can run the project on an assembly.
When I try to start the application, I get errors:

```
"C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3\bin\java" -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:CICompilerCount=3 -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1564081530.jar org.grails.cli.GrailsCli run-app --plain-output
|Running application...
E:\WORK\newggloor\src\main\java\email\EmailHelper.java:4: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.*;
^
E:\WORK\newggloor\src\main\java\email\EmailHelper.java:5: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.*;
^
E:\WORK\newggloor\src\main\java\email\EmailHelper.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        ^
  symbol:   class Session
  location: class EmailHelper
E:\WORK\newggloor\src\main\java\email\EmailHelper.java:24: error: package javax.mail does not exist
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                              ^
                                         ^
E:\WORK\newggloor\src\main\java\email\EmailHelper.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                    InternetAddress.parse(email));
                    ^
  symbol:   variable InternetAddress
  location: class EmailHelper
E:\WORK\newggloor\src\main\java\email\EmailHelper.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
            Transport.send(message);
            ^
  symbol:   variable Transport
  location: class EmailHelper
E:\WORK\newggloor\src\main\java\email\EmailHelper.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
                 ^
  symbol:   class MessagingException
  location: class EmailHelper
12 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error |
Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: I added the jar file as a library.] Added to the module newggloor_main.

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependency in build.gradle

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use the grails mail plugin. Put this into your build.gradle:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6"
```

Comment: it is not suitable for me

Comment: @Alex432 but why?